# How to change clientId, authority values after MSAL has already read the configuration? [msal]

Tags: angular, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I am using Azure AD B2C with a multi-tenant application. User first enters email, then a drop-down is filled based on the tenant he is related to (tenant1, tenant2, tenant3). The user selects tenant1 so he will be redirected to tenant1's custom login page(background and logo).

So after the user selects the value in drop-down based on that API returns clientId_, authority_, postLogoutRedirectUrl_ I want to set these values to MsalModule.forRoot()_

How can I achieve this? Please help !!

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/1403).

Comment: Hello Akash, are you still looking for help, or did the sample provided by Derisen work for you?

Comment: @Nishant-MSFTIdentity Our case is different, We have reloaded the application that solved our problem. But we are yet to find a concrete solution.

Comment: It seems you are trying the change the `Appsettings` configuration and load in MsalModule.forRoot() with `clientid`, `authority`. There is no direct way for now but there is an workraround for it. Please refer this [similar issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/943#issuecomment-555759454)

Answer (score 0):

Its an old thread, but for others who end up here like I did, this is well documented in the MSAL JS documentation now. Its as simple as injecting an instance of MsalService in your component, and setting its instance property with a new PublicClientApplication instance.

```
constructor(private msalService: MsalService){}

changeTenant(tenant) {
this.msalService.instance = new PublicClientApplication({
  auth: {
    clientId: tenant.clientId,
    authority: tenant.authority,
    redirectUri: tenant.redirectUri
  }
});
}
```

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/docs/multi-tenant.md#changing-the-tenant